# DAX solutions for RLS taking up too much memory?

Tags: powerbi, dax, row-level-security

Current code which checks current logged in user's name against Logon column. End goal being to find all rows of Customer_SK associated with that user. VALUESrow is a measure finding all those SK matches and removing duplicates.

```
RLSFilterCustomer = 

VAR FindUser =
    IF (
        SUMX (
            FILTER (
                'User Security_RLS',
                UPPER ( 'User Security_RLS'[User Logon] ) = UPPER ( USERNAME () )
                    || UPPER ( 'User Security_RLS'[User Logon] ) = UPPER ( USERPRINCIPALNAME () )
            ),
            // Check connection to customer  
            FIND (
               
                UPPER ( 'User Security_RLS'[ShipToCustomer_SK] ),
                [AllowedRow],
                
                ,
                0
            )
               
        ) > 0,
        1,
        0
    )
RETURN
    FindUser
```

Apologies if explanation was bad. Still pretty new to this.

Comment: Do you really need to convert all the UPNs to upper case?  What kind of data is in AllowedRow?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Allowed Row is the measure that removes the duplicates from the customer SK column in the facts table by using CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANK(VALUES('Facts'[Customer_SK]),1))

Comment: The data case is pretty inconsistent. I assume that's why they add the upper.

Comment: Well normalizing the UPNs and filtering on a Customer dimension rather than the fact table would both probably help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard answer for simplifying RLS evaluation is to structure your model so that you filter the data entitlement table by the UPN and have that flow filters to whatever table you want to secure.  So create a table in your model with two columns `(Customer_SK, [User  Logon])` enumerating every allowed Customer_SK for each [User Logon].  Configure this table with a bi-directional relationship to the main Customer table, and put a simple RLS filter on it like:

```
'User Security_RLS'[User Logon] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()
```

Comment: Appreciate the feedback but in this case I'd just like to know if the code here can be done more simply? For the moment I'm working with the model structure that's there.